# issue with execution of query in php

Tags: php

I have an problem in following code how can i manage sql string because it unable to retrieve question  problem in string how can i correct string

```
    <?php

                       $chapter = $_SESSION['chapters'] ;
                   if(isset($chapter)) 
                      {
                         $nchapter = count($chapter );
                        echo("You selected $nchapter chapters:<br> ");
                    for($i=0; $i < $nchapter; $i++)
                       {
                         ($chapter[$i] . " ,");

                             echo  $var1 = $chapter[$i] . " <br>";

                          $_SESSION['var1'] = $var1;
                        $db = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
                        $db_select = mysql_select_db("db",$db);
                      echo  $var1 ;
                     echo $sql = "select * from ".$_SESSION['tcsub']." where                                       chapter='$var1'";
      $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
             echo  $data= htmlspecialchars_decode($row['question'], ENT_QUOTES);
          }
     }

  } 
?>
```

Comment: What does the echod SQL give you? Note that you better first set the $SQL variable, and then echo the $sql on the next line

Comment: The field can scroll, and then you see the rest of the query..

Comment: Sry for wrong answer. mysql_fetch_array should work in your case.

Comment: Thanks @JelleFerwerda , sorry, I over looked, comments taken out

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "select * from ".$_SESSION['tcsub']." where chapter='".$var1."'";
echo $sql
```

try this, and tell us what the echo returns. Probably your $_SESSION does not know the right table?